Deploying Jenkins on EC2 instance
I’m running Jenkins on an Ubuntu EC2 instance, and recently, the Jenkins service fails to start correctly. The service enters a restart loop and eventually stops. When I check the logs with journalctl -xeu jenkins.service, I see the following sequence of events:
Jenkins service starts and begins extracting from the WAR file.
A warning appears: ContextHandler#setContextPath: Empty contextPath.
Jenkins seems to initialize various components but then the service deactivates itself with no clear error message.
Here’s a portion of the log:
Aug 27 22:38:38 ip-172-31-21-213 jenkins[5102]: WARNING o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#setContextPath: Empty contextPath
Aug 27 22:38:58 ip-172-31-21-213 jenkins[5102]: INFO hudson.WebAppMain#contextInitialized: Jenkins home directory: /var/lib/jenkins found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars>
Aug 27 22:38:59 ip-172-31-21-213 systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Deactivated successfully.

Steps I’ve tried:
Checked that Java is installed and is the correct version for Jenkins.
Verified that no other service is using port 8080.
Checked /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log for more detailed error messages, but it doesn't provide additional clues.
Reinstalled Jenkins, but the problem persists.
Environment:
Ubuntu (EC2 instance)
What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it to get Jenkins up and running again?
